# Loading Dialog on HTTP call OptimusHTTP

Tags: android, rest, httprequest, webservice-client

im using OptimusHTTP library on my android project. im trying to show loading if my app is contacting server. my problem is why my progress dialog does not dismiss. here is my code.

```
public void connectREST()
{
    //using data json dummy
    String SERVER = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";
    OptimusHTTP client = new OptimusHTTP();
    client.enableDebugging();
    client.setMethod(OptimusHTTP.METHOD_GET);


    //parameter
    ArrayMap<String, String> params = new ArrayMap<>();
    params.put("email", "abc@abc.com");
    params.put("pass", "abc");



    //make request
    ArrayList<HttpReq> refHttpReqList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        //mprogressdialog.show(this, "", "Loading", true);
        // makeRequest() returns the reference of the request made
        // which can be used later to call the cancelReq() if required
        // if no request is made the makeRequest() returns null
        HttpReq req = client.makeRequest(MainActivity.this, SERVER, params, responseListener);
        if (req != null)
            refHttpReqList.add(req);

       mprogressdialog.show(this, "Loading", "Wait while loading...");
        if (mprogressdialog != null && mprogressdialog.isShowing()) {
            mprogressdialog.dismiss();
        }



    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private final OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener responseListener = new OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public  void onSuccess(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        //mprogressdialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



    @Override
    public void onFailure(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
};
```

i know that this library (OptimusHTTP) is using asnyc when contacting server. 
is there any configuration whether im using sync or async on the http connection ?
what if im include get method in some async code (double async) ?

i know that my question seem like some newbie question. but it takes learn process to become a pro :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@navotera : You can show a ProgressDialogue just before making a request and when the request completes , under the listener just dismiss the progress dialogue.

i.e

```
...

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...
...
// Initialize the progressdialog
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting");
...
...
// Show the progressdialog just before making a request  
progressDialog.show();
// Make the request
req = client.makeRequest(MainActivity.this, SERVER_URL, params,new OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener(){
    @Override public void onSuccess(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
            // Dismiss the progressdialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
      }

      @Override public void onFailure(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
            // Dismiss the progressdialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You see this library (OptimusHTTP) is using asnyc when contacting server.But why did you update UI on the same thread ?

```
private final OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener responseListener = new OptimusHTTP.ResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public  void onSuccess(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        //mprogressdialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     }



   @Override
   public void onFailure(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
   }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... u mean when i try to dismiss the progress bar (on my code i can uncomment //mprogressdialog.dismiss()) it wont work because im asking android on the different thread than UI work..... so loading.dismiss() wont work... ?

Comment: i change my code as you suggest with this : 
`
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    mprogressdialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
`
it still not work, where did i doing wrong? thanks anyway..

Comment: what wrong with toast sir ? does it has any effect ?

Comment: You know the listener is running on the. main thread,so  you can try to cancel the comment for dialog.dismiss?If toast has shown,the dialog should dismiss too

Comment: unfortunately toast is showing but progressdialog not dismissed. but thank anyway

and thanks to let me know that the listener is running on the main thread, just for my new knowledge :)